# select box manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to dynamically change the option value of a select tag. Is this possible? When I say value, I mean the "Change Me" portion. If this is possible, can someone please show me how?

```
<option value="0">Change Me</option>
```

Comment: yes it is possible, do u have something u want to work on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch and modify the combobox item's text as follows:

```
$("#MyCombo option:selected").text()
```

Note: @shaz; thanks for your comment, my mistake!

Comment: Thank you Sander, that worked. I can accept your answer in 5 minutes. BTW: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Please explain why the options need to be selected in order to fetch or change the text. I have a working example [here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DtAVc/1/) indicating otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

You will need to look at the options available using a select tag.

```
<select id='selection'>
 <option value='0'>Value 0</option>
 <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
 <option value='2'>Value 2</option>
 <option value='3'>Value 3</option>
 <option value='4'>Value 4</option>
 <option value='5'>Value 5</option>
</select>
```

the javascript

```
var select = document.getElementById('selection');

// to get the currently selected item, use the `selectedIndex` property.
var index = select.selectedIndex; // 3 in case of value 2 selected

// to change its text
select.options[index].innerHTML = 'the new value';
```

is this what u are looking for?

Comment: I think what I needed was `text()`. That did the trick for me. Thank you for your help.